# Java DB (Derby) Database Alter Column Size

Tags: java, database, derby, javadb

I'm trying to alter the size of a field in my Java DB Database. I just can't seem to do it. My current data type is `varchar(50)` and I want to update it to `varchar(150)`.

Comment: What database are you using?  MySQL?  PostgreSQL?  SQL Server?  Derby?  Something else?

Comment: JDBC is just a tunnel between your code and the database so you need your SQL to be valid for the particular database you are using.

Comment: Java DB used to be called (and perhaps is still referenced as ) Derby

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved:

`ALTER TABLE [table] ALTER COLUMN [column] SET DATA TYPE [type];`

I wasn't using the `SET DATA TYPE` function and was instead just trying to redeclare it by using `ALTER COLUMN [column] [type];`

Answer (score 1):

For mysql you can do this way

```
alter table table_name modify col_name varchar(150)
```

JDBC codes

```
PreparedStatement pt =connection.prepareStatement("alter table table_name modify col_name varchar(150)");
pt.executeUpdate();
```

In ms sql server use this command

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name]
ALTER COLUMN [Column_name] varchar(150)
```

Comment: Does this work with JavaDb (aka Derby?). I don't believe it does

Comment: @BrianAgnew I am not sure about Derby. This was very old question and at that time tags were java,database,netbeans and jdbc